# RDS MySQL to DMS CDC fails after running for some time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication, aws-dms

I'm having trouble with my AWS DMS setup.

The RDS used as source is MySQL. I have enabled the binlogging, set the retention to 168 and set innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit to 1.

I have a DMS replication instance dms.t3.micro with 50GB Storage and Replication Task set to Full load, ongoing replication.

The task runs the full load successfully and after some hours the CDC fails.

The CloudWatch log throws: `2023-06-07T12:01:05:564949 [SOURCE_CAPTURE  ]E:  Read next binary log event failed; net_safe_read error 1236 (binlog truncated in the middle of event; consider out of disk space on master; the first event 'mysql-bin-changelog.017941' at 480, the last event read from '/rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog.017941' at 123, the last byte read from '/rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog.017941' at 499.) [1020403]  (mysql_endpoint_capture.c:1076)`

I tried increasing the DMS Replication Instance to `dms.t3.medium` and the storage to 200GB after which I `resumed` the replication task but it fails immediately with the same error.

Do I need to restart the task from the begining?

The point is to send data to Kinesis data stream and feed everything to Elasticsearch. The full load gets everything from the database to the elastic so no problem there.

Here is the replication task settings JSON:

```json
{
    "Logging": {
        "EnableLogging": true,
        "EnableLogContext": false,
        "LogComponents": [
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TRANSFORMATION"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "SOURCE_UNLOAD"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "IO"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TARGET_LOAD"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "PERFORMANCE"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DETAILED_DEBUG",
                "Id": "SOURCE_CAPTURE"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "SORTER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "REST_SERVER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "VALIDATOR_EXT"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TARGET_APPLY"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DETAILED_DEBUG",
                "Id": "TASK_MANAGER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TABLES_MANAGER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "METADATA_MANAGER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "FILE_FACTORY"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "COMMON"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "ADDONS"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "DATA_STRUCTURE"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "COMMUNICATION"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "FILE_TRANSFER"
            }
        ],
        "CloudWatchLogGroup": "dms-tasks-rds-repl-inst",
        "CloudWatchLogStream": "dms-task-VL6DWJ4KWIARRSVXVD3UODFFH5XQEE5VBNYAMCY"
    },
    "StreamBufferSettings": {
        "StreamBufferCount": 3,
        "CtrlStreamBufferSizeInMB": 5,
        "StreamBufferSizeInMB": 8
    },
    "ErrorBehavior": {
        "FailOnNoTablesCaptured": true,
        "ApplyErrorUpdatePolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "FailOnTransactionConsistencyBreached": false,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottlingMax": 1800,
        "DataErrorEscalationPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "RecoverableErrorStopRetryAfterThrottlingMax": true,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottling": true,
        "ApplyErrorFailOnTruncationDdl": false,
        "DataTruncationErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorInsertPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "EventErrorPolicy": "IGNORE",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "RecoverableErrorCount": -1,
        "DataErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "TableErrorEscalationPolicy": "STOP_TASK",
        "RecoverableErrorInterval": 5,
        "ApplyErrorDeletePolicy": "IGNORE_RECORD",
        "TableErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "FullLoadIgnoreConflicts": true,
        "DataErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "TableErrorPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE"
    },
    "TTSettings": {
        "TTS3Settings": null,
        "TTRecordSettings": null,
        "EnableTT": false
    },
    "FullLoadSettings": {
        "CommitRate": 10000,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesApplied": false,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesNotApplied": false,
        "MaxFullLoadSubTasks": 8,
        "TransactionConsistencyTimeout": 600,
        "CreatePkAfterFullLoad": false,
        "TargetTablePrepMode": "DROP_AND_CREATE"
    },
    "TargetMetadata": {
        "ParallelApplyBufferSize": 0,
        "ParallelApplyQueuesPerThread": 0,
        "ParallelApplyThreads": 0,
        "TargetSchema": "",
        "InlineLobMaxSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadQueuesPerThread": 0,
        "SupportLobs": true,
        "LobChunkSize": 0,
        "TaskRecoveryTableEnabled": false,
        "ParallelLoadThreads": 0,
        "LobMaxSize": 32,
        "BatchApplyEnabled": false,
        "FullLobMode": false,
        "LimitedSizeLobMode": true,
        "LoadMaxFileSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadBufferSize": 0
    },
    "BeforeImageSettings": null,
    "ControlTablesSettings": {
        "historyTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "HistoryTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "StatusTableEnabled": false,
        "SuspendedTablesTableEnabled": false,
        "HistoryTableEnabled": false,
        "ControlSchema": "",
        "FullLoadExceptionTableEnabled": false
    },
    "LoopbackPreventionSettings": null,
    "CharacterSetSettings": null,
    "FailTaskWhenCleanTaskResourceFailed": false,
    "ChangeProcessingTuning": {
        "StatementCacheSize": 50,
        "CommitTimeout": 1,
        "BatchApplyPreserveTransaction": true,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMin": 1,
        "BatchSplitSize": 0,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMax": 30,
        "MinTransactionSize": 1000,
        "MemoryKeepTime": 60,
        "BatchApplyMemoryLimit": 500,
        "MemoryLimitTotal": 1024
    },
    "ChangeProcessingDdlHandlingPolicy": {
        "HandleSourceTableDropped": true,
        "HandleSourceTableTruncated": true,
        "HandleSourceTableAltered": true
    },
    "PostProcessingRules": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/dms-cdc-error-1236-msql.
The error is caused usually due to sync_binlog value on source. It should be set to 1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This configuration is set to 1, so that shouldn't be the problem.